# extjs multiselect list from json string

Tags: javascript, extjs, multi-select

I am trying to create a multiselect list from json store, which is in this format

```
[{"photo_id":1,"file_name":"test.JPG","x":123,"y":456},{"photo_id":2,"file_name":"test2.JPG","x":321,"y":765}]
```

The multiselect list populates the rows but it doesn't show the file_name in the list

```
var storeVar = new Ext.data.Store({
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: ['photo_id', 'file_name'],
   data: store // contains the json string
});
```

and here is the multiselect box

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
bodyPadding: 10,
frame: true,
width: '100%',
items: [
    {
        anchor: '100%',
        displayField: 'file_name',
        valueField: 'photo_id',
        store: storeVar ,
        xtype: 'multiselect',
        fieldLabel: 'Select an image',
        allowBlank: false
    }
]
})
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you edit your post again because you have given an invalid json data, in `{..."y":456,{"photo_id...}`

Comment: ok, my bad let me edit it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grigor, you can use [Ext.JSON.decode](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.JSON-method-decode) to decode your string in json format:

```
var storeVar = new Ext.data.Store({
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['photo_id', 'file_name'],
    data: Ext.JSON.decode(store) // contains the json
});
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/mV5AX/)

Comment: You are awesome Molecule. Thanks for the response. Very useful!

Comment: why do I get 110 when I do store.length? Clearly there isn't 110 results in that string. hmm

Comment: @Grigor, `store.length` represents ammount of properties which `store` contains as an Object. There is special function that returns ammount of all items - `store.getTotalCount()`.

Comment: I ended up doing this `eval('('+store+')').length`

Comment: how would I put the list into a multiselect list instead of combobox with multiselect property enabled? Or if thats not possible, how would I add a select with holding shift feature, where you select an item, hold shift and select another and whatever is in between is being selected? Also, if thats not possible either, how would I make the list show in grid, then add the same shift select feature to the grid?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the creation of the Store with the definition of a model: The line

```
extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
```

has no effects on a Store, check examples on documentation [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store)

I can't comment/edit on questions so I write it in a new answer.